# psql: FATAL: Could not obtain a transaction ID from GTM. The GTM might have failed or lost connectivity

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, postgres-xl

I want to create a `postgres-xl` cluster. The cluster includes 5 nodes, 1 GTM, 2 Coordinator and 2 Datanodes. The following are the details of nodes

```
GTM:   
hostname=localhost  
nodename=gtm  
IP=127.0.0.1  
port=20001

Coordinator1：  
hostname=localhost  
nodename=coord1  
IP=127.0.0.1  
pooler_port=30011，port=30001  

Coordinator2：  
hostname=host2  
nodename=coord2  
IP=10.4.6.36  
pooler_port=30012，port=30002  

Datanode1：  
hostname=localhost  
nodename=dn1  
IP=127.0.0.1  
pooler_port=40011, port=40001  

Datanode2：  
hostname=host2  
nodename=dn2  
IP=10.4.6.36  
pooler_port=40012, port=40002
```

I have installed *pgxc_ctl* and added */usr/local/pgsql/bin* to *PATH* for postgres. I have Configured ssh authentication to avoid inputting the password for pgxc_ctl. I have edited postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf on both nodes.

Then I built the cluster as follows:

```
$ pgxc_ctl
PGXC$  add gtm master gtm localhost 20001 $dataDirRoot/gtm    
PGXC$  add coordinator master coord1 localhost 30001 30011 
       $dataDirRoot/coord_master.1 none none
PGXC$  add coordinator master coord2 10.4.6.36 30002 30012 
       $dataDirRoot/coord_master.2 none none
```

after adding coord2, i got the following

> psql: FATAL:  Could not obtain a transaction ID from GTM. The GTM might have failed or lost connectivity

```
PGXC$  add datanode master dn1 localhost 40001 40011 
       $dataDirRoot/dn_master.1 none none none
PGXC$  add datanode master dn2 10.4.6.36 40002 40012 
       $dataDirRoot/dn_master.2 none none none
```

after adding dn2, I got the following error

> ERROR:  Failed to get pooled connections
>   HINT:  This may happen because one or more nodes are currently unreachable, either because of node or network failure.
>    It's also possible that the target node may have hit the connection limit or the pooler is configured with low connections.
>    Please check if all nodes are running fine and also review max_connections and max_pool_size configuration parameters

But when I monitor all the nodes, it shows

```
PGXC$  monitor all
Running: gtm master
Running: coordinator master coord1
Running: coordinator master coord2
Running: datanode master dn1
Running: datanode master dn2
```

I could not connect to **coord2** by running

```
 psql -h 10.4.6.36 -p 30002 -U user -d postgres
```

It shows

> psql: FATAL:  Could not obtain a transaction ID from GTM. The GTM might have failed or lost connectivity

But I could connect to the **coord1** by running

```
psql  -p 30001 -U user -d postgres
```

I could ping host2 from my localhost without the password. 
I need to resolve the above errors. Any help?
Adding the configuraion:

```
pgxcInstallDir=$HOME/pgxc
pgxcOwner=$USER     
pgxcUser=$pgxcOwner     
tmpDir=/tmp                 
localTmpDir=$tmpDir         
configBackup=n                  
configBackupHost=pgxc-linker    
configBackupDir=$HOME/pgxc      
configBackupFile=pgxc_ctl.bak   
dataDirRoot=$HOME/DATA/pgxl/nodes

#---- Coordinators ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

coordMasterDir=$dataDirRoot/coord_master
coordSlaveDir=$HOME/coord_slave
coordArchLogDir=$HOME/coord_archlog
coordExtraConfig=coordExtraConfig   
cat > $coordExtraConfig <<EOF
#================================================
# Added to all the coordinator postgresql.conf
# Original: $coordExtraConfig
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
listen_addresses = '*'
max_pool_size=300
max_connections=200
hot_standby = off
EOF

#---- Datanodes -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

datanodeMasterDir=$dataDirRoot/dn_master
datanodeSlaveDir=$dataDirRoot/dn_slave
datanodeArchLogDir=$dataDirRoot/datanode_archlog
datanodeExtraConfig=datanodeExtraConfig 
cat > $datanodeExtraConfig <<EOF
#================================================
# Added to all the datanode postgresql.conf
# Original: $datanodeExtraConfig
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_directory = 'pg_log'
listen_addresses = '*'
max_pool_size=300
max_connections=200
hot_standby = off
EOF
#---- GTM ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------      
gtmName=gtm
gtmMasterServer=localhost
gtmMasterPort=20001
gtmMasterDir=$dataDirRoot/gtm


coordNames=( coord1 coord2  )
coordMasterServers=( localhost 10.4.6.36  )
coordPorts=( 30001 30002  )
poolerPorts=( 30011 30012  )
coordMasterDirs=( $dataDirRoot/coord_master.1 $dataDirRoot/coord_master.2  )
coordMaxWALSenders=( 5 5  )
coordSlave=n
coordSlaveServers=( none none  )
coordSlavePorts=( none none  )
coordSlavePoolerPorts=( none none  )
coordSlaveDirs=( none none  )
coordArchLogDirs=( none none  )
coordSpecificExtraConfig=( coordExtraConfig coordExtraConfig  )
coordSpecificExtraPgHba=( none none  )


datanodeNames=( dn1 dn2  )
datanodeMasterServers=( localhost 10.4.6.36  )
datanodePorts=( 40001 40002  )
datanodePoolerPorts=( 40011 40012  )
datanodeMasterDirs=( $dataDirRoot/dn_master.1 $dataDirRoot/dn_master.2  )
datanodeMasterWALDirs=( none none  )
datanodeMaxWALSenders=( 5 5  )
datanodeSpecificExtraConfig=( datanodeExtraConfig datanodeExtraConfig  )
datanodeSpecificExtraPgHba=( none none  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you show us your configuration?

What are your `max_connections` and `max_pool_size`?  What did the `initdb` show for your kernel?  My guess is that when you add the datanode2 (dn2) you don't have enough connections.

You have:

> cluster includes 5 nodes, 1 GTM, 2 Coordinator and 2 Datanodes. The
>   following are the details of nodes.

Postgres-xl specific: 
`max_pool_size=300`
`max_coordinators=2`
`max_datanodes=2`

In case of *Coordinator* (minimal settings):
`max_connections=100`# number of connections accepted from application(s)
`max_prepared_transactions = 100` # same as number of connections

In case of *Datanode* (minimal settings):
`max_connections=200`  # 2 coordinators 
`max_prepared_transactions=2` #Specify at least total number of Coordinators in the cluster.

Excerpt from the Postgres(-xl) documentation

### *max_connections (integer)*

> Determines the maximum number of concurrent connections to the database server. The default is typically 100 connections, but might
>   be less if your kernel settings will not support it (as determined
>   during initdb). This parameter can only be set at server start.
>
> When running a standby server, you must set this parameter to the same or higher value than on the master server. Otherwise, queries
>   will not be allowed in the standby server.
>
> In the case of the **Coordinator**, this parameter determines how many connections can each Coordinator accept.
>
> In the case of the **Datanode**, number of connection to each Datanode may become as large as max_connections multiplied by the number of
>   Coordinators.

### *max_pool_size (integer)*

> Specify the maximum connection pool of the Coordinator to Datanodes. Because each transaction can be involved by all the
>   **Datanodes**, this parameter should at least be max_connections
>   multiplied by number of Datanodes.

**Edit** - for update question configuration

Try this:

- Coordinator

  ```
  max_connections=100
  max_pool_size=300
  ```
- Datanode (you have 2 datanodes defined)

  ```
  max_connections=200 
  max_pool_size=500
  ```

Comment: I have already configured using max_pool_size and max_connection. But did not work. I have edited the question.

Comment: @PratheeshM I see now.  Did you read the text of max_pool size?  It says that this parameter should be" at least max_connections multiplied by number of Datanodes".  That means that if you have `max_connections=200` and two datanodes you have to have `max_pool_size=400`.

Comment: `max_connections=` has for coordinator different.  It says how many connections the Coordinator can accept.

Comment: @PratheeshM No, I'm sorry that did not help.  Did re-create the cluster or just changed the values?  I think it may be need to recreate the cluster and first get rid of `psql: FATAL: Could not obtain a transaction ID from GTM.` - did switch of your firewall?  e.g. `chkconfig iptables off`; `service iptables stop`.  Maybe there could be an issue there.

Comment: Second thing I just noticed `gtmMasterServer=localhost` - you are listening to localhost so how can you connect to other nodes - try `gtmMasterServer=<your_gtm_ip>` to listen to all interfaces.  Also I did not find a `pooler_port=(integer)` -  which is used for both the Coordinator and Datanode processes to connect to other nodes!!!